# UITextInput - How to get it to add standard selection gesture recognizers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, richtext

Is there a way to persuade iOS to attach the standard gesture recognizers to a custom view that implements UITextInput?

I have implemented all methods of UITextInput, I am drawing selection, the cursor and marking myself. I found that long-pressing on marked text shows the rectangular system loupe. This tells me that there are situations when the touch handling IS provided by the system.

Is there a method to get the standard selection gestures also working without having to add a bunch of touch handling code and drawing the loupes yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no. You have to implement all of that yourself. I spent a great deal of time in the Advanced Text lab while at WWDC, bugging the guys who wrote most of Core Text. There are some odd bits where system functionality shines though, if you use a label to do some of the drawing. But in the current SDK, we are out of luck.